# Stack implementation using nodes

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

### Purpose

Implement a [`Stack`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) with `push`, `pop`, and `peek` methods.

- The `push` method should add an element to the "top" of the `Stack`.
- The `pop` method should remove the "top" element from the `Stack`.
- The `peek` method should return the "top" element of the `Stack`.

### Approach

I decided to create a `Node` class to represent the elements in a `Stack`. The `Node` class would have a `data` field
and a `previous` field that would reference another `Node`. By having this `previous` field one can "chain" `Node`s together.

For my `Stack` class, I decided to set the `head` (i.e. the `Node` at the "top" of the `Stack`) value to `null` on initialization.
I also decided to throw `Exception`s when calling `peek` or `pop` for an empty `Stack` (i.e. when the `head` value is `null`).

I could see an argument to not throw `Exception`s but rather return `null` for `peek` or nothing for `pop` (since it's `void`).
However, `null` is a valid value for an `Object`, and since a `Stack` is made up of `Object`s, I think returning
`null` when calling `peek` for an empty `Stack` could be confusing.

```java
public class Node<T> {
  T data;
  Node<T> previous;

  public Node(T data, Node<T> previous) {
    this.data = data;
    this.previous = previous;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public Node<T> getPrevious() {
    return previous;
  }
}

public class Stack<T> {
  Node<T> head = null;

  public Stack() {
  }

  public T peek() {
    if (this.head == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to peek element for an empty stack");
    }

    return this.head.getData();
  }

  public void push(T data) {
    this.head = new Node<>(data, this.head);
  }

  public void pop() {
    if (this.head == null) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to remove element from an empty stack");
    }

    this.head = this.head.getPrevious();
  }
```

Comment: Users often know, how many items there are on a stack – but not always! See graph searching algorithms for example. How do you imagine retrieving all the nodes from a stack with no indication of stack emptiness? That would force users to enclose _every_ `peek()` and `pop()` within try-catch instructions. You should definitely return `null` instead of throwing exceptions, or add some `isEmpty()` or `isNonEmpty()` testing method to the `Stack` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't throw `RuntimeException`: they are not specific, and hence difficult to catch.  (Otherwise, you might as well drop the null checks and let it fail naturally with `NullPointerException`, which is also a kind of `RuntimeException`.) You should make your own exception subclass, or use `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

It would also make sense to support an `isEmpty()` method, to give the user a fair chance to avoid the exception.

Two spaces per level of indentation is too narrow and unconventional for my taste, and could also encourage excessive nesting.  Four or eight spaces would be acceptable.